# CSV file upload cancel Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Im wondering whats the best way to handle this.

I have a form_for with a couple of text_fields to fill and with a form.file_field(:file) , so a user can upload a csv file into the database. There is also a Save and a Cancel button, both are for the whole form to be saved or cancelled. Cancel is set to return to main index page, and not to create this form.

If a user tries to upload a csv file and clicks Cancel or closes the browser page, it doesnt cause the upload to stop, and results in duplicates when a user uploads the same csv again, thinking last one was cancelled, when in fact few rows from last one were actually uploaded.

The question I have is whats the smartest way to "cancel" the upload completely whilst its already uploading it, if a uses clicks Cancel or if a user closes the browser window?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should have to rely on users closing the browser window - maybe you could use a validator to ensure that 100% of the .CSV file is uploaded before it saves, otherwise it  redirects to the main index?